# Trouble with mix SKView and NSVew in Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, variables, nsview, skview

In my project I mix SKView with standard NSView objects in 1 window. And now I trying to take some information from SKscene (mouseDown location) and show it in label near skview object.
I tried to use global variables and assign value for it in skview method

```
-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
   CGPoint location = [theEvent locationInNode:(self)];  
  // location = (10, 15) - example
   currentPointPosition = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y); 
  //currentPointPosition = (10, 15)
}
```

but when check it from nsbutton, like this:

```
- (IBAction) updateButton:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"currentPoint over skview methods: 
  %0.3f : %0.3f", currentPointPosition.x, currentPointPosition.y);
  //currentPointPosition = (0, 0)
  //other code
}
```

...it remain like after init (annul). 
Is it even possible to mix these techs? 
ps: sorry for my english 
[Project screen:](http://s8.postimg.org/kdmu36h6d/2014_09_19_20_02_30.png) http://s8.postimg.org/kdmu36h6d/2014_09_19_20_02_30.png

Comment: Is the problem that currentPointPosition is 0x0? Then post how and where you declared that variable.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, currentPointPosition declared in .h file, in Interface. Also I tried declared it as Property, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, and where and how do you assign a position to it? If you don't assign anything to it it will be 0x0.